# Connect my code with elasticsearch

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch server installed in a machine:

this is a part of config:

```
transport: {
  bound_address: inet[/192.168.1.42:9300]
  publish_address: inet[/192.168.1.42:9300]
}
http: {
  bound_address: inet[/192.168.1.42:9200]
  publish_address: inet[/192.168.1.42:9200]
  max_content_length_in_bytes: 104857600
}
```

And I try from Scala program with elasticsearch java library to connect to this server.
This is a code for connect to server using nodeBuilder :

```
val builder:Node = nodeBuilder()
  .client(true)
  .local(false)
  .loadConfigSettings(false)
  .clusterName("elasticsearch")
  .settings(
      ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
      //.put("network.bind_host", "192.168.1.42")
  .put("network.host", "192.168.1.42")
      .put("transport.tcp.port",9300)
      .put("http.port",9200)
      .build()
).node()

val client:Client = builder.client()
```

but receive this exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at actors.DaasySocketActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(DaasySocketActor.scala:25)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at actors.DaasySocketActor.aroundReceive(DaasySocketActor.scala:17)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9300]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:389)    
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:91)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9300]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:389)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.start(InternalNode.java:231)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:166)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:91)
        at lib.int_elasticsearch$.<init>(int_elasticsearch.scala:55)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85)
        at lib.int_elasticsearch$.<clinit>(int_elasticsearch.scala)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.start(InternalNode.java:231)
        ... 12 more
        at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:166)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /192.168.1.42:9300
```

If I try to connect with this code works well:

val client:Client = new TransportClient()
     .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("192.168.1.42", 9300))

but i want connect with node client and not with TransportClient.

What do the error? 
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Strip the hostname and port out from the node client. A node client is a node in its own right, so setting the hostname/port to another node is why you have a clash (manifested in the bind exception).

```
val builder:Node = nodeBuilder()
  .client(true)
  .local(false)
  .loadConfigSettings(false)
  .clusterName("elasticsearch")
  .node()

val client:Client = builder.client()
```

A node joins the cluster. A transport client just connects to a node.

Comment: Ok, but my code and elasticsearch are not on the same server, how my code know the ip for connect to elasticsearch? Thanks